# How to get rid of magic numbers background

Tags: java, colors, awt, magic-numbers

I'm getting magic numbers for jpanel background. Is there a way to get rid of this since it's bad practice:

```
panel.setBackground(new color (255,255,0));
```

How can I have custom colors too?

Comment: Use constants.  What do the numbers 55, 265, and 44 actually mean?  Define those in some static final variable.

Comment: that's not even valid Java - there is no `color` class, and `265` is not a valid color value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There are some common colors. such as *red,blue*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html), etc.

```
panel.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
```

but if you want to set your own colors you must create a object with your colors,

```
public static final Color myColor = new Color(55,265,44);
```

then set it,

```
panel.setBackground(myColor);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just define your own palette somewhere, eg:

```
class Colors {
  public static final Color BACKGROUND_COLOR = new Color(55,265,44);
  public static final Color PALE_RED = new Color(...);
}

panel.setBackground(Colors.BACKGROUND_COLOR);
```